# C Double Pointer to Structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

I am trying to work out a double pointer to a structure in C and cannot figure out what is going wrong... The simple source is below:

```
typedef struct
{
    int member;
} mystruct;

void myfunc(mystruct **data)
{
    (*data)->member = 1;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mystruct **data;

    myfunc(data);

    printf("member = %d\n", (*data)->member);
}
```

A similar question was asked here: [How to work with pointer to pointer to structure in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346730/how-to-work-with-pointer-to-pointer-to-structure-in-c) on how to modify a member of a structure through a double pointer. The solution was the syntax `(*data)->member = 1;` which makes sense. But in my little application here, I receive a seg fault when executing that line. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Allocation aside, +1 for a well asked question.

Comment: Normally, the only reason you would use a pointer to a pointer to a struct would be a function needs to change where a pointer points.  For example, if `myfunc` were allocating instances of `mystruct` or perhaps retrieving them from a list/queue/etc, it would make sense.  But if you are only manipulating the content of the struct, there's no reason for a 'double pointer'.

Comment: to put some context on this, I am not trying to create this. I am trying to create a USB interface using libusb-1.0. One of the libraries functions requires a double pointer to a structure as an argument. So I was trying to work out how I was going to provide that. Everyone has been dead on with their responses though. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to point to something if you are going to dereference a pointer. Try this:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    mystruct actualThing;
    mystruct *pointer = &actualThing;
    mystruct **data = &pointer;
    myfunc(data);

    printf("Member: %d", (*data)->member);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You received a segfault because you did not allocate a struct.

The value of `data` is garbage, so it is pointing to some place in memory that is not owned by your process, or is otherwise inaccessible.

You need to first allocate an object of type `mystruct`.  Here is a working example for you: http://ideone.com/XIdJ8

Answer (score 5):

`data` is not initialized, and hence doesn't point to any sensible memory address. Moreover, there is no `mystruct` structure floating around, so there really isn't even any sensible data to point to. For your example, you want to:

1. Create a `mystruct`.
2. Make a pointer to it.
3. Make a pointer to that pointer.

Comment: wow, can't believe I didn't think of that. all 3 of these replies are correct.

Comment: It's just one of the many bugs in humans. But we all live and learn :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to pass the double pointer to a library function, you don't need to create a variable for it. You make a normal pointer variable, initialize it to point to appropriate storage (if required by the function), then pass the address of the pointer (thus creating the double-pointer "on the fly").

I've never used libusb, so I'll give an example using a standard library function. From the manpage:

```
   #include <stdlib.h>

   long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

It only *looks* like a double-pointer. It's really a simulated-pass-by-reference single pointer. Allowing the function to return extra information besides its normal return value. `strtol` returns a long integer but it also can tell you at what point the string contents stopped looking like a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *str = "99RED BALLOONS";
    char *what;
    long num;

    num = strtol(str, &what, 10);
    printf("Quantity: %ld;    Description: %s;\n", num, what);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Quantity: 99;    Description: RED BALLOONS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you can try this:

```
void main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
   mystruct *data;
   myfunc(&data);
   printf("member = %d\n", data->member);
}
```

This works for me in C++ and not needed to point another variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing it a pointer, but the pointer isn't pointing at anything.

This may be more useful:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mystruct data;
    mystruct *ptr = &data;
    myfunc(&ptr);
    printf("member = %d\n", (*ptr)->member);
}
```