# C - Inserting into sorted linked list with double pointers

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to create a sorted linked list in C with the following code but I am getting a segmentation fault before any of my input is printed.  I believe it is because I'm checking `((*link)->value < val)` in my while loop, but at the beginning, it is `NULL`.  I also tried adding a conditional for if there are no elements in the list but that didn't work.  How could I check to see if the value to add is smaller without getting seg. fault?

```
struct NodeTag {
    int value;
    struct NodeTag *next;
};
typedef struct NodeTag Node;

typedef struct {
    Node *head;
    int length;
} List;

void insertSorted(List *list, int val) {
    Node **link = &(list->head);

    while (*link != NULL || (*link)->value < val) {
        //move node to correct place in list
        link = &((*link)->next);
    }
    //create new node
    Node *n = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->value = val;

    //set next to null
    n->next = NULL;

    //insert new node
    *link = n;
}
```

Here is printList:

```
void printList(List *list) {
    printf("%d elements :", list->length);

    for (Node *n = list->head; n; n = n->next)
        printf( " %d", n->value);
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

Input: `72 19 47 31 8 36 12 88 15 75 51 29`

Expected output: `8 12 15 19 29 31 36 47 51 72 75 88`

Comment: You need to change the || to &&

Comment: This only outputs the smallest 4 out of 12 values.  The input is: 
72 19 47 31 8 36 12 88 15 75 51 29
and the list prints as:
8 12 15 29

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C Double Pointer to Structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638612/c-double-pointer-to-structure)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some problems in your code:

- you use `||` instead of `&&`.  If the `next` member is `NULL`, you are at the end of the list, insert right there.
- the argument name is `list` but you use `link` in the body
- you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C and it is considered counterproductive, especially if you forget to include `<stdlib.h>`.
- you do not test for allocation failure
- you do not link the rest of the list to the inserted node.
- the function should return a pointer to the inserted node, giving the caller a chance to check for memory allocation failure.
- you should not comment the obvious.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

Node *insertSorted(List *list, int val) {
    Node **link = &list->head;
    while (*link != NULL && (*link)->value < val) {
        //skip this node
        link = &(*link)->next;
    }
    //create new node
    Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (n != NULL) {
        n->value = val;
        n->next = *link; // link the rest of the list
        *link = n;   //insert new node
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the line:  Node **link = &( list->head );
at the beginning of the code

Comment: @AaronHiller: OK, and you also forgot to post the definitions of `List` and `Node`.

Comment: Added it, how can I get it to not skip values?

Comment: @AaronHiller:  Does the corrected code skip values?  Can you post a complete program with the printing function and the main function along with the input values and the expected output?

Comment: Posted.  The current code(with && rather than ||) seems to be skipping some values